# utl_file.fopen failing Occasionally

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql, oracle11g, utl-file

Everyone,

We have a set of 8 jobs which runs in parallel on Unix server. Those jobs calls Oracle stored procedure. All those procedures does a set of DB operations (on different tables) and at the end creates files in Unix server. (Each job creates a file in different names. But puts in same folder)

Recently, we are seeing random failures with error message **"ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536".** Each day one or two job fails, while creating the error report. When the job is rerun there is no issues. We couldn't reproduce the issue in lower environment.

The folder has all access granted. This jobs have been running for more than an year with no issues. Any ideas appreciated.

Based on my analysis:-
DB Operations have completed without any issues. There is no file created (not even an empty one). So it failed while encountering fopen.

Sample code

```
DECLARE
 IN_CONT_TYPE   varchar2(100) := 'HARDWARE_ATTRIBUTES' ;
    in_batch_name  ccpm_epslz_control.push_batch_name%TYPE := 'HARDWARE_ATTRIBUTES_20181211062540';
  l_file_type utl_file.file_type;
  file_record_hold_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

/*DB Operations*/

      l_file_type       :=utl_file.fopen('ERR_FOLDER',l_file_name,'W');
      utl_file.put_line(l_file_type, 'count of input records filtered based on errors:');
      utl_file.put_line(l_file_type, '-----------------------------------------------');
      utl_file.put_line(l_file_type, l_col_name_print);
      OPEN file_record_hold_cur FOR l_select_stmt_bus;
      LOOP
        FETCH file_record_hold_cur INTO l_putline_stmt_bus;
        EXIT
      WHEN file_record_hold_cur%notfound;
        utl_file.put_line(l_file_type, l_putline_stmt_bus);
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE file_record_hold_cur;
      utl_file.fclose(l_file_type);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      Dbms_Output.put_line ( DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE() );
    END;
```

> ERROR MESSAGE:-  ORA-20051: Internal Error in file
>   generationORA-06512: at "MYPACKAGE", line 84                                                                   
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536

Comment: You've only shown a single error message; can you include the whole stack of errors?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole ! I have added the whole stack of errors

Comment: `ORA-20051` is a **user-defined** exception. It may be declared in `mypackage`, certainly it's raised there. So it seems this is not something we can help with, except to advise you to fire up a text editor, open the source code for `mypackage` and look hard at the code leading up to line 64.

Comment: Yes, ORA-20051 is an user defined exception. And it raises when it is unable to create the file. Any idea why am getting ORA-06512 at sys.utl_file?

Comment: Full disk, perhaps?

Comment: I checked, there is space.

Comment: @Georgy Can you please explain how that will help me?